# Creating ordered list of certain type css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a ordered list with html/css like this :

```
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ol>
```

Where they would render like this (including parenthesis):

```
(1) One
(2) Two
```

Comment: for what it's worth: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Flist-style-type

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [css counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters). Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/JaPZE/).

markup:

```
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ol>
```

css:

```
ol
{
    counter-reset: section; 
    list-style: none;
}
li:before
{
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "(" counter(section) ") ";    
}
```

Comment: There's a very good Smashing article about it : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/12/css-generated-content-counters/

Comment: @crush Doesn't matter... you don't have to be first to get rep. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Try the following code. It might not work in old versions of IE or Firefox.

UPDATED: Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Mx9f/).

CSS:

```
ol {
  counter-reset: list;
}
ol li {
  list-style: none;
}
ol li:before {
  content: "(" counter(list) ") ";
  counter-increment: list;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>Number 1</li>
  <li>Number 2</li>
  <li>Number 3</li>
  <li>Number 4</li>
  <li>Number 5</li>
  <li>Number 6</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @ErikMes: You must be doing something wrong then - every version of Firefox *in existence* has supported CSS counters from the get-go.

Comment: Good idea. If you want to know more why? You can click here.http://www.w3cplus.com/css3/css-generated-content-counters.html

Answer (score 1):

See the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VzEsr/

HTML

```
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: count 0;
}

ol li {
    counter-increment: count 1;
}

ol li:before {
    content: '(' counter(count) ')';
}
```